# How do I send JSON data to Django app via Python urllib?

Tags: python, django, urllib

I am trying to send JSON data to my django web app using python urllib but with no luck.
This is my code;

Python application:

```
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/web_app"
values = {'name':'Paul','age':12}
jdata = {'data':values}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'Content-Type':'application/json'})
try:
   resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
   the_result = resp.read()
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
   return "Reques Failed!"
```

My Django Web App:

```
@csrf_exempt
def web_app(request):
     print "In My webapp"   # This never get printed!
     data = request.POST['data']
     return HttpResponse("Thankyou...")
```

The request seems not to be hitting the Django `web_app` function, because the first print in the function is not executed!

Added:
note if i remove the data from the request in the urllib2.request then everything works as expected!!

What am i missing?

Comment: can you access the page in a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your urlconf look like? If it looks like `'^web_app/$'` and `APPEND_SLASH=True` in settings, which is default, you need to use `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/web_app/"` (note the suffix slash). Or else Django would try to redirect `/web_app` to `/web_app/` if there is no matching, then complains about redirecting a `POST` request.

Also, its meaningless to set `'Content-Type':'application/json'` for HTTP request, you could set this and break [the requirement of urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) by passing it a JSON-dumped string; but then you should parse `request.body` by yourself instead of using `request.POST`. `application/json` is normally for specifying the `Content-Type` of response.

Comment: +1, i also had a bad malformed urlconf pattern, it was like this initially url(r'$', 'myapp.views.home') without the "^" in front of the $ sign. I changed it to look like r'^$' and added the suffix slash. Thanks